# How to wait until keyboard is opened in flutter?

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout

I need to scroll page when textfield is focused.
So I used scroll_to_index plugin(https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index).
But It operate well only when keyboard is already opened.
If I tap the textfield when keyboard is not opened, it doesn't scroll the page.
I think it is because page is scrolled before the keyboard is opened.

In my opinion, the problem seems to arise because the code works this way.

1.tap a textfield (linked Focusnode has Focus)
2. It try to scroll the page to the target. But because now keyboard is not opened yet, target is already in view. So It looks like nothing happened.
3. Keyboard is opened, and hide the content.

**auto_scroll.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';

class MyCustomScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomScrollViewState createState() => _MyCustomScrollViewState();
}

class _MyCustomScrollViewState extends State<MyCustomScrollView> {

  AutoScrollController _autoScrollController = new AutoScrollController();
  List<FocusNode> nodes = List<FocusNode>.generate(3, (index) => FocusNode());

  Future _scrollToIndex(int index) async {
    await _autoScrollController.scrollToIndex(index,
        preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.end);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for(var i  =0;i<3;i++) {
      nodes[i].addListener(() {
        if(nodes[i].hasFocus) _scrollToIndex(i);
      });
    }
  }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        controller: _autoScrollController,
    slivers: [
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              CupertinoTextField(
                focusNode: nodes[0],
                onEditingComplete: (){
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nodes[1]);
                },
              ),
              AutoScrollTag(
                key: ValueKey(0),
                controller: _autoScrollController,
                index: 0,
                child: Container(height: 300, color : Colors.green)
              ),
              CupertinoTextField(
                focusNode: nodes[1],
                onEditingComplete: (){
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(nodes[2]);
                },
              ),
              AutoScrollTag(
                  key: ValueKey(1),
                  controller: _autoScrollController,
                  index: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    color : Colors.green,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text("Here should be visible!!!!"),
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              CupertinoTextField(
                focusNode: nodes[2],
              ),
              AutoScrollTag(
                  key: ValueKey(2),
                  controller: _autoScrollController,
                  index: 2,
                  child: Container(height: 300, color : Colors.green)
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      )
    ],
  ),
    );
    }
}
```

This is the code. When I tap on the second textfield, it should scroll to show all the red containers below the second textfield, but it doesn't.
But when the keyboard is up, clicking on the second text field works as desired.

**What I expected when I tap 2nd Textfield**
[image]

**What actually happened**
[image]

I know that just giving focus to textfield is enought to scroll to the textfield. But in my application I have a Positioned bar just above the keyboard, so I have a situation where the Positioned bar covers the text field. This is why I use scroll_to_index.

So what I want to do is wait for the keyboard to come up, and then when the keyboard comes up, run the _scrollToIndex function. How can I wait until keyboard is opened? or there are any good solution for this problem? Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem here. Did you manage to solve this by using the flutter_keyboard_visibility? The plugin helps me react to changes in the keyboard visibility, but it still doesn't let me scroll properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility). There are 2 ways of implementation: [with provider](https://github.com/MisterJimson/flutter_keyboard_visibility/blob/master/example/lib/demo_with_provider.dart) and [with listener](https://github.com/MisterJimson/flutter_keyboard_visibility/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart).